# What is a correct reader root configuration?

Tags: extjs

I have got json from server:

```
[
"list",
[
    {
        "name": "NAME_1"
    },
    {
        "name": "NAME_2"
    },
    {
        "name": "NAME_3"
    }
]
```

]

My question is: What is a correct store reader root parameter to get records like below?

```
[
{
    "name": "NAME_1"
},
{
    "name": "NAME_2"
},
{
    "name": "NAME_3"
}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

There is no root, so no `root` configuration, just exclude it, or set it to null.